# Why error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './ML/model.pth' occurs?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pytorch

Error

> l_1      |     from Ml import demo_model 
> ml_1      |   File "/app/Ml/demo.py", line 84, in 
> ml_1      |     model = torch.load('./ML/model.pth',  map_location='cpu') 
> ml_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 584, in load 
> ml_1      |     with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file: 
> ml_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 234, in _open_file_like 
> ml_1      |     return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode) 
> ml_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 215, in **init** 
> ml_1      |     super(_open_file, self).**init**(open(name, mode)) 
>  
> **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './ML/model.pth'**

occurs when starting the docker container.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./server/requirements.txt /app

COPY ./server/Ml/model.pth /app/Ml/

COPY ./server/Ml/demo.py /app/Ml/

RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD gunicorn -b=0.0.0.0:8443 -w=4 project.app:app --timeout 2000
```

The line of code where the error occurs:

```
best_model = torch.load('./ML/model.pth',  map_location='cpu')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a typo: the folders are `Ml` (small "l") while in the code it is `ML` (capital "L").